# Cannot find archive manager for Visual Studio 2015 Community with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to follow the tutorial at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/ 
However, the last step is all about the Archive Manager. Select the Android project right click and a context menu with "Archive..." should appear. I can't find it within Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which Xamarin verison are you using?

Comment: I am using Xamarin Android version 6.1. Thank you Stefan, found the problem I must install Xamarin 4.2 (with Xamarin Android 7.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least Xamarin Android 7.0 as described in the topic ["Publishing to Google Play"](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_3_-_publishing_an_application_on_google_play/) to use the distribution feature.

Comment: Thank you, that will do!