# Xamarin android deployment using Visual Studio

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment, cross-platform

I am using visual studio community edition and i am try to deploy an application by following the tutorial

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/

When it comes to second step "Archive" option is missing in my visual studio .
Should we enable this option from some settings or its going to be there by default?

Also from  https://www.xamarin.com/compare-visual-studio  i can see that Visual Studio Community Edition can be used for deploy the apps to private and public stores

```
So how can i do Archive option using VS 2015 Community edition
```

Comment: Are you using Release configuration? It's not available on debug.

Comment: Did you see the hyperlink note on this? [Docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#archive)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes its in release mode

Comment: @Jon I cant see anything on hyperlink notes on the link can you please confirm link is correct one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721166/cannot-find-archive-manager-for-visual-studio-2015-community-with-xamarin  i think this is the reason , looking to do it manually

Comment: Given you are on Xamarin for VS 4.2+, you should be able to right click your Android project in any configuration(`Release` should be used when publishing) and select the `Archive` option.

Comment: @JonDouglas for us archive option itself is missing

Comment: If you go to `Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio`, what version of `Xamarin for Visual Studio` do you see?

Comment: @JonDouglas     
   
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

Xamarin   4.1.2.18 (fcbe082)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android   6.1.2.21 (1cf254d)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Comment: You will need to follow the other directions here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/visual-studio-xa-4.2.6-to-6.1/ Or you can update your Xamarin (Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other) to the latest stable and follow the original guide.

Comment: @JonDouglas Finally  i updated my Xamarin as per instructions and i can see archive options . Thanks for the helps and comments and proud that my first android app is out to store :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on an old version of Xamarin and thus the Archive options are different. You can view them here:

[https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,testing,_and‌​*metrics/publishing*‌​an_application/part_‌​2-_signing_the_andro‌​id_application_packa‌​ge/visual-studio-xa-‌​4.2.6-to-6.1/](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,testing,_and%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B_metrics/publishing_%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Ban_application/part_%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B2-_signing_the_andro%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bid_application_packa%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bge/visual-studio-xa-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B4.2.6-to-6.1/)

However I would recommend that you update your Xamarin for Visual Studio tooling via (Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other) to the latest stable and follow the guide you linked above(https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/)